# Asking to run function in new window, but it still runs on the parent window

Tags: javascript, popup, onload

I have defined a new window in javascript like this:

```
var r = window.open("", "rgroup", "status=1,width=800,height=600");
```

and I have a function that prints certain output, and I am trying to run it like this:

```
r.onload = runproduct();
```

but it stills run on the main parent window.

I must add, I am not trying to give the order of running from the parent window, but from a second new window, so to make it short, I have:

1) Main window (function is appearing here)

2) Second window (I am giving the order from here)

3) Third window (this is where I want the output to happen)

Is it easy to fix? I am scratching my head as for why giving the order to run a function on the second window from the main, works, but giving the order to a third window from a second window doesn't...

Thank you for any clarification! This is a bit confusing...

Answer (score 1):

Functions enclose the variable context at the time they're *created*, not when they're run.  I.e. your `runproduct()` is using the variable scope chain of it's creating context (the main window).  Regardless of when it's run, any references to globals or other closure variables will be to the state in the main window.

To fix this, you can write your `runproduct()` function to explicitely refer to the window reference.  E.g.

```
var r;
function runproduct() {
  console.log(window); // refers to main window
  console.log(r); // refers to second window
}
r = window.open(...etc...);
```

Comment: Thanks. Did that and is still not working, but at least I have something else to take into account now.